# Java Swing Panel displaying image strange behaviour

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I have no idea what the heck is going on while I'm trying to render an image on a JPanel in a JFrame. In fact I just want an image displayed in a fixed position on my JFrame.To achieve this I have a JPanel of a fixed size (min, max, pref size set) on my JFrame. On press of a button, I add another panel to mentioned panel, having the same size. The "child" panel has an overriden paint method to draw an image. So far so good, once I press the button and add that child panel, nothing happens at all. If I then click on the empty panel, the image is drawn as it should be, not overflowing the bounds of the child panel. However, all other components width increases drastically, stretching them out of the JFrames bounds. One would think that at least a scrollbar would appear, but no, the components are then out of reach. I'm attaching two screenshots displaying that very logic behavior.

The code is as follows:

```
  void setPoster(BufferedImage poster) {
    ImagePanel ip = new ImagePanel(poster);
    ip.setSize(new Dimension(222, 327));
    panelPoster.add(ip);
    ip.setSize(new Dimension(222, 327));
}
```

Inside ImagePanel:

```
    @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    System.out.println("Paiting imagepanel with size " + getSize());
}
```

Before screenshot:

[image]

After screenshot:

[image]

Could anyone enlighten me on what could possibly occur here?

Comment: What layout manager are you  using?

Comment: @swingMan I guess I'm using the default one. I tried using BorderLayout on the Panel holding the Panel with the image, did not work. Just tried setLayout(null) on the JFrame, also no effect. I'm wondering why Swing just doesn't leave things where they are. Edit: Setting Layout(null) on the JPanel inside the tabbed pane fixed the problem. Now I only need to get the image to be shown again, since that stopped working without layout.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, don't use ant of the methods that set some kind of size. Instead, override the getter methods.

Comment: @user1803551 Are you sure overriding is necessary? That would cause a bunch of more or less unnecessary classes for me.

Comment: Without an MCVE it's hard to tell, but that is a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the strange resizing by setting the layout to null on both the JFrame and the JPanel inside my tabbed pane.

```
    setLayout(null);
    jPanel4.setLayout(null);
```

**Anyway, that's not needed when using the JLabel instead of the JPanel to hold the image.**

However, my ImagePanel would not draw the image anymore, so I replaced it by a JLabel which draws the image just fine:

```
    void setPoster(BufferedImage poster) {
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(poster));
    panelPoster.add(imageLabel);
    imageLabel.setSize(new Dimension(222, 327));
}
```

Note that without setting the size of the JLabel, it won't display anything.

Comment: `null` layout is almost certainly wrong. It will not work well on other screens with different resolution and OS. You should really fix it the right way.

Comment: @user1803551 after replacing the JPanel with a JLabel the null layout is no longer needed.